# Vim Formatprg Set Working Directory

Tags: vim, formatting

:)

I'm just working with formatting programs in combination with *Vim*. So far I used `neoformat` as plugin to handle this for me. But it laggs in some points and so I tried to solve it myself by define the `formatprg` myself. The point is that some (maybe all?) formatters have a configuration in the projects root directory. Cause it is necessary that the code gets formatted with this configuration and not the global default one, I need to set up the `formatprg` for this.

By experiments with a simple script I used as formatter, I found out that the script/formatter is executed in *Vim's* current working directory. I used to have my *Vim* instance automatically be in the projects root directory, so this whole thing should work and the formatter find the projects configuration. But I don't want to rely on this. So I'm interested if it is possible to pass a working directory to the `formatprg` independently from *Vims* current one. I couldn't found such option in the documentations, but that doesn't have to mean it does not.

As an alternative I thought about a script which takes the formatter program and its arguments as passed to `formatprg`, but first change the working directory before call this and pass the output to its own stdout. So call it a wrapper which simply make sure the directory is correct.
So instead of something like `setlocal formatprg=prettier\ --stdin` using it with `setlocal formatprg=formatwrapper\ prettier\ --stdin`.

What are your opinions?
Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function that returns your project's root directory based on the presence of a `package.json` file in the current directory or a parent directory:

```
function! FindRoot() abort
    return fnamemodify(findfile('package.json", '.;'), ':h')
endfunction
```

You can use it in your `formatprg` like this:

```
let &l:formatprg = 'cd ' . FindRoot() . ' && prettier --stdin'
```

Comment: Ah yes. Forgot about that I can use the variable instead of using set. 
Idea how to make this change directory more general, so I don't have to do this for each `formatprg` I define?

Comment: This looks quite generic already but you could simply factor it into a single function.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for ur help! :)